# Cannot connect from eclipse java to mongo db and I'm not using Maven/Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb

I have simple java program that tries to connect to my only mongodb local instance and I want to insert some data. I have these referenced jar files when running the code:

```
 - C:\Users\olgad\Downloads\jsoup-1.11.2.jar
 - C:\Users\olgad\Downloads\mongodb-driver-3.6.1.jar
 - C:\Users\olgad\Downloads\bson-3.0.4.jar
 - C:\Users\olgad\Downloads\java-json.jar\java-json.jar
 - C:\Users\olgad\Downloads\mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar\mongo-java-driver-2.9.1.jar
 - C:\Users\olgad\Downloads\mongodb-driver-core-3.0.1.jar
```

My mongodb version is 3.4.10

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {                       
            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);

            DB database = (DB) mongoClient.getDatabase("test"); 
            DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("myCol");

            DBObject dbObject = (BasicDBObject) JSONObject.stringToValue("{'name':'mkyong', 'age':30}");
            collection.insert(dbObject);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            // Prints what exception has been thrown
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }    
    }
}
```

The error that is printed is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/DBRefCodecProvider     at
>   com.mongodb.MongoClient.(MongoClient.java:89)     at
>   prvCrawler.Main.main(Main.java:30)

Thanks in advance! Olga

Comment: You should try using Maven/Gradle, not manually listing JAR files

Comment: can you explain it a little more detailed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one too many jars with conflicting packages. Remove all the mongodb related jars first and start over.

You have two options:

Manually downloading the jar ( Use one of the below option ). Use same versions for all jars.

1. Download the [`mongo-java-driver uber jar`](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/) which contains all the necessary libraries packaged as one.
2. Download the jars ([`mongodb-driver`](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver/), [`mongodb-driver-core`](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/), and [`bson`](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/mongodb/bson/)) individually.

Use [`Maven/Gradle`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver/getting-started/installation-guide/#installation) for downloading the jars.

Comment: thanks, that solved my problem, I downloaded them manually!